# Validação Resultado JSON URL

Tags: php, json

O seguinte estou precisando buscar se determinado série foi aprovada, caso não seja aprovada não deixe o usuário prosseguir. Preciso pegar a informação de um url, que traz o seguinte resultado se a série não for aprovada {"serial": "281924406", "aprovada": false} se for aprovada {"serial": "281924406", "aprovada": true}. Veja o comando

$url =  "https://10.0.10.22/runin/clones/". $_POST["NUNOTA"] ."/aprovada/";

$resultado = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

```
var_dump($resultado);
```

O resultado impresso é o seguinte:
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {["serial"]=string(9) "281924406" ["aprovada"]=>bool(false)}

Como que eu posso transforma em uma variavel para fazer a validação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por exemplo, pode aceder aos items do objecto individualmente da seguinte forma:

```
$url = "https://10.0.10.22/runin/clones/". $_POST["NUNOTA"] ."/aprovada/";
$resultado = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

if ($resultado->aprovada) {
echo "Serial " . $resultado->serial . "aprovada.";
} else {
echo "Serial " . $resultado->serial . "não aprovada.";
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/sdo.sample.getset.php

Comment: Funcionou blz, muito obrigado.

Comment: Ainda bem. Se funcionou marque a resposta como útil. vl